# Raphael - How delay an animation with set elements

Tags: raphael, delay

I'd like create an echo effect with many circles with smaller circle than the next one.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        circle = paper.circle(...);
        myset.push(circle);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean like some sort of puddle/splash effect with the circles changing their radius over time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is an example that may do what you want, if not, there should be enough bits in it to show how you could. You don't really need a set, but you could add it if you want to do something with it later.

The animation element includes a delay parameter you can use, and then apply the animation to the shape.

```
var paper = Raphael("container"), myCircle, myAnimation;

myAnimation = Raphael.animation({r: 100, opacity: 1}, 3000, "linear", function() { this.remove() });

for( var c=1; c<10; c++ ) {
    myCircle = paper.circle(10,10,10)
                    .attr("opacity", 0.2)
                    .animate( myAnimation.delay(c*300) );
}
```

With a working jsfiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/9QmRe/9/

Comment: But I've pun the "myAnimation" instance inside the for, cause "r" depends by "c"... can I just set "myAnimation's r" inside the for?

Comment: Yes, thats no problem, I only left it outside as it wasn't changing then. You can include it inside, so something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/9QmRe/12/

Comment: I already did that, but I thought to modify just an attribute on myAnimation to prevent so many instances of Raphael.animation

Comment: I'm not quite sure if thats possible or not (just as I'm not sure how to add a delay to a normal animate without using the animation object). You could probably do it with a setTimeout instead of animation/delay, but ultimately then you have a number of setTimeouts ready to be called. So I'm not sure if there is any real gain from that. I think if you have concurrent animations, it may make sense to have separate elements. If they are one after each other, maybe its better to have just one animation or something. You could also possibly delete the animation element on completion as well.